# How to achieve a straight regression line in a log-log sns.regplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to recreate this plot created with R in Python:

[image]

This is where I got:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

sns.regplot(x='Platform2',y='Platform1',data=duplicates[['Platform2','Platform1']].dropna(thresh=2), scatter_kws={'s':80, 'alpha':0.5})
plt.ylabel('Platform1', labelpad=15, fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Platform2', labelpad=15, fontsize=15)
plt.title('Sales of the same game in different platforms', pad=30, size=20)

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xticks([1,2,5,10,20])
ax.set_yticks([1,2,5,10,20])
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_xlim([0.005, 25.])
ax.set_ylim([0.005, 25.])

plt.show()
```

I think I am missing some conceptual knowledge behind the logarithmic values I plotted here. Since I did not change the values themselves but the scale of the graph I think I am doing something wrong. When I tried changing the values themselves I was not successful.

What I wanted was to show the regression line like the one in the R plot and also show the 0s in the x and y axes. The logarithmic nature of the plot does not allow me to add the 0 limits in the x and y axes. I found this StackOverflow entry: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972754/how-to-scale-the-x-and-y-axis-equally-by-log-in-seaborn) but I was not able to make it work. Maybe if someone can rephrase it or if someone has any suggestions on how to move forward it would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn's `regplot` creates either a line in linear space (`y ~ x`), or (with `logx=True`) a linear regression of the form `y ~ log(x)`. Your question asks for a linear regression of the form `log(y) ~ log(x)`.

This can be accomplished by calling `regplot` with the `log` of the input data.
However, this will change the data axes showing the `log` of the data instead of the data themselves.  With a special tick formatter (taking the power of the value), these tick values can be converted again to the original data format.

Note that both the calls to `set_xticks()` and `set_xlim()` will need their values converted to log space for this to work. The calls to `set_xscale('log')` need to be removed.

The code below also [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl) most `plt.` calls to `ax.` calls, and adds the `ax` as argument to `sns.regplot(..., ax=ax)`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()
p1 = 10 ** np.random.uniform(-2, 1, 1000)
p2 = 10 ** np.random.uniform(-2, 1, 1000)
duplicates = pd.DataFrame({'Platform1': 0.6 * p1 + 0.4 * p2, 'Platform2': 0.1 * p1 + 0.9 * p2})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

data = duplicates[['Platform2', 'Platform1']].dropna(thresh=2)
sns.regplot(x=np.log10(data['Platform2']), y=np.log10(data['Platform1']),
            scatter_kws={'s': 80, 'alpha': 0.5}, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Platform1', labelpad=15, fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Platform2', labelpad=15, fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Sales of the same game in different platforms', pad=30, size=20)

ticks = np.log10(np.array([1, 2, 5, 10, 20]))
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
formatter = lambda x, pos: f'{10 ** x:g}'
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(formatter)
lims = np.log10(np.array([0.005, 25.]))
ax.set_xlim(lims)
ax.set_ylim(lims)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

To create a `jointplot` similar to the example in R (to set the figure size, use `sns.jointplot(...., height=...)`, the figure will always be square):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()
p1 = 10 ** np.random.uniform(-2.1, 1.3, 1000)
p2 = 10 ** np.random.uniform(-2.1, 1.3, 1000)
duplicates = pd.DataFrame({'Platform1': 0.6 * p1 + 0.4 * p2, 'Platform2': 0.1 * p1 + 0.9 * p2})

data = duplicates[['Platform2', 'Platform1']].dropna(thresh=2)
g = sns.jointplot(x=np.log10(data['Platform2']), y=np.log10(data['Platform1']),
                  scatter_kws={'s': 80, 'alpha': 0.5}, kind='reg', height=10)

ax = g.ax_joint
ax.set_ylabel('Platform1', labelpad=15, fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Platform2', labelpad=15, fontsize=15)

g.fig.suptitle('Sales of the same game in different platforms', size=20)

ticks = np.log10(np.array([.01, .1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20]))
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
formatter = lambda x, pos: f'{10 ** x:g}'
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(formatter)
lims = np.log10(np.array([0.005, 25.]))
ax.set_xlim(lims)
ax.set_ylim(lims)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example of jointplot]

Comment: Hey Johan, I just wanted to thank you because not only has the explanation worked very well for me, but I also understood very clearly what you meant. So thanks a lot for taking the time to answer this in detail!